# Update all documents in a collection with random numbers

Tags: mongodb, random

I am trying to update all documents in a collection with random numbers.

Each document should have a different number.

My current code

```
db.myDoc.update(
  { rand : { $exists : false } },
  { $set : { rand: Math.random() } },
  { multi : true }
)
```

populates ALL documents with the SAME random value.

How to fix?

Comment: set a variable before and use that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can make use of the [`cursor.forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) cursor method in the mongo shell to achieve this:

```js
db.myDoc.find({rand: {$exists : false }}).forEach(function(mydoc) {
  db.myDoc.update({_id: mydoc._id}, {$set: {rand: Math.random()}})
})
```

Comment: Nice idea (not sure about performance), but I keep getting Fri Nov 21 17:20:06.451 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: @checklist, Are you probably using a hyphen (-) instead of underscore(_) in the query?  Please copy and paste the query you are running.

Comment: On one line: db.myDoc.find(rand: {$exists : false }).forEach(function(mydoc) {db.myDoc.update({_id: mydoc._id}, {$set: {rand: Math.random()}})})

Comment: Sorry, I was missing curly braces inside the find().  Fixed now.  Try the updated query in my answer.

Comment: Does this answer eliminate the possibility of a collision?

Comment: @regretoverflow, in the OP's query, `Math.random(`) is called just once and the same value is used to update all documents in the collection.  But by using `forEach()`, we are calling `Math.random()` for every document.  So, it does eliminate the possibility of a collision.

Comment: @AnandJayabalan - Math.random() could generate the same random number twice, they are not guaranteed to be unique. You really should index that property, and check if the number generated exists in the collection before assigning it to a document. IAW, math.random can generate the number 1 many times, and the original question stated they needed to be unique.

Comment: Thanx! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @regretoverflow, while I do understand that `Math.random()` could generate the same number twice, **I think** it's good enough for this query as it is seeded by time.  I'll let the OP decide if it suits his use-case or not.  Thanks though.  Like I mentioned before, the query in the OP invokes Math.randon() just once, whereas my version invokes it for every document in the collection, which is what I wanted to highlight.

Comment: My main reason for stating that was to help others, by letting them know that Math.random() will cause collisions. Random == unique is a common mistake and by documenting this with comments it may help someone that sees this answer and might assume that, since the original question states 'unique'

Comment: Expecting math.random to generate unique numbers is not a good idea.  Any future readers attempting to use this snippet for that purpose should NOT DO THAT. The seed used doesn't matter; what matters in this case is the size of the cofactor multiplying the number (possible generated number space) and the size of the dataset involved.

Answer (score 12):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator allows applying a custom javascript function to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language.

For instance, in order to update documents with a random value:

```
// { "x" : 1 }
// { "x" : 2 }
db.collection.updateMany(
  { rand: { $exists: false } },
  [{ $set:
    { rand:
      { $function: {
          body: function() { return Math.random(); },
          args: [],
          lang: "js"
      }}
    }
  }]
)
// { "x" : 1, "rand" : 0.7012578283384967  }
// { "x" : 2, "rand" : 0.21041874709692365 }
```

---

`$function` takes 3 parameters:

- `body`, which is the function to apply.
- `args`, which contains the fields from the record that the function can take as parameter. In our case we don't need any reference to the document itself in order to compute a random value, thus the empty array.
- `lang`, which is the language in which the `body` function is written. Only `js` is currently available.

Note that this is now way more efficient than a find/foreach option since everything is done server side in one pass.

Comment: Found out "$function" and other server-side js is not allowed on Mongo Atlas free tier :(

Answer (score 5):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4.2`, the [`$rand`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/rand/#mongodb-expression-exp.-rand) aggregation operator provides a random float between 0 and 1 each time it is called:

```
// { "x" : 1 }
// { "x" : 2 }
db.collection.updateMany(
  { rand: { $exists: false } },
  [{ $set: { rand: { $rand: {} } } }]
)
// { "x" : 1, "rand" : 0.22252333583221115 }
// { "x" : 2, "rand" : 0.9811303782541574  }
```

Comment: Note that it's important to use `[{ $set: … }]` and not just `{ $set: ... }`. The latter is not a pipeline and thus doesn't know about `$rand`.